# A variant of Bernstein's localization principle

Tags: schwartz-distributions, p-adic-analysis, p-adic-groups

Bernstein's localization principle says the following:
Let $G$ be an l-group and $X,Y$ be two l-spaces. Assume $X$ is a $G$-space. Let $q:X\rightarrow Y$ be a continuous map of l-spaces, such that each fiber $q^{-1}(y)$ is $G$-invariant. Then if $S^*(q^{-1}(y))^G=0$ for all $y\in Y$, then $S^*(X)^G=0$. Here $S(X)$ is the Bruhat-Schwarts function space on $X$, and $S^*(X)$ is the linear dual of $S(X)$, i.e., the distributions on $X$.
(The reference for this is J.Bernstein's paper "P-invariant distributions on GL(N) and the classification of unitary representation on GL(N)", LNM, 1041, 1984).

I want to know if the following variant is correct or not. As above, let $G$ be an l-group, $X,Y$ be two l-spaces. Suppose that $X$ has a $G$-action. Let $Z$ be a closed $G$-invariant subset of $X$. Let $q:X-Z\rightarrow Y$ be a continuous map. For each $y\in Y$, suppose that $Z$ is closed in $q^{-1}(y)\cup Z$.

My question is:

If $S^*(q^{-1}(y)\cup Z)^G=S^*(Z)^G$ for all $y\in Y$, can we conclude that $S^*(X)^G=S^*(Z)^G$?

(If $Z$ is the empty set, then this is exactly the above Bernstein's localization principle.)

If this is false, is it possible to add more restrictions on $Z$ so that this is true?

Thanks in advance.